# Create Command to run and give an input to Windows Application

Tags: c

I want to make a Console Application for Windows Embedded Compact which will take an integer array input from User and that array will be passed as an argument to one of the function in the Application.SO,basically I want to make a Command to execute that application and also the command will contain the Integer array which the user want to pass to the Application. My Programming language is C.
I don't know how to make personalized command to be run from command prompt.
Any help or link for this will be greatly Appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

[This is where you start](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html) !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

They're called Command Line Arguments

basically you pass it to `main()` like so:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   // argc is atleast 1 (contains the no. of arguments passed)
   // argv[0] contains the image name and path
   // argv[1] = first argument, argv[2] = second argument and so on..
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aniket for the link. But this is for Linux.
I want it for Windows.How can I make a command which would be including my input array, and pass it to the command prompt?